# How to limit return results

Tags: sql, oracle

My query returns duplicate rows and I want to return only one row.

```
select  papf.Full_Name,
          papf.Employee_number,
          papf.DatE_OF_BIRTH,
          peef.last_update_date
        /*,
        petf1.ELEMENT_NAME as MedicalSchemeName*/
from per_all_people_f papf
    ,per_all_assignments_f paaf
    ,PAY_ELEMENT_ENTRIES_F peef
    ,pay_element_types_f petf
    --,fnd_user fnu    
    where (papf.Employee_number) not in
(select 
        papf1.Employee_number

from per_all_people_f papfinner
    ,per_all_assignments_f paafinner
    ,PAY_ELEMENT_ENTRIES_F peefinner
    ,pay_element_types_f petfinner

where   paafinner.person_id = papfinner.person_id
and     peefinner.assignment_id = paafinner.assignment_id
and     peefinner.element_type_id = petfinner.element_type_id

and     upper(petf1.ELEMENT_NAME) like '%Condition%'

and     SYSDATE BETWEEN  papfinner.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND    papfinner.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
and     SYSDATE BETWEEN  paafinner.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND    paafinner.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
and     SYSDATE BETWEEN  peefinner.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND    peefinner.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
and     SYSDATE BETWEEN  petfinner.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND    petfinner.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
)
and     SYSDATE BETWEEN  papf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND    papf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
and     SYSDATE BETWEEN  paaf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND    paaf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
and     SYSDATE BETWEEN  peef.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND    peef.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
and     SYSDATE BETWEEN  petf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND    petf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
and     upper(petf.ELEMENT_NAME) not like '%Condition%'
and     rownum <= 10000
order by peef.last_update_date;
 ....
```

This query works properly and returns the correct results but the results are duplicated. I only need one unique row

Comment: Just use `rownum <= 1`

Answer (score 1):

One of the tables you are joining one is returning doubles or more. I bet it is "peef". Perhaps you can only show the `MAX(last_update_date)` and roll the rest up against that. So just GROUP BY.

```
select  papf.Full_Name,
        papf.Employee_number,
        papf.DatE_OF_BIRTH,
        last_update_date = MAX(peef.last_update_date)
...

GROUP BY
    papf.Full_Name,
    papf.Employee_number,
    papf.DatE_OF_BIRTH
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: If you need to return many fields then the group by may become less efficient. For the three fields in your query it should be fine, however, if you are returning all fields then you will get better performance if you generated a ROW_NUMBER in your detail PARTIONED by the fields in the group by above ORDERED DESC, then create a outer query that returns all fields with a WHERE clause limiting your derived row_number field=1